# Suggestions for implementing visual link analysis into web app

Tags: implementation

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to implement visual link analysis into a web application.  I'm hoping for something that will compare to i2's Analysis Notebook without all the cost.

I have found [ThinkMap SDK](http://www.thinkmap.com/thinkmapsdk.jsp) (built on Java) and [JuiceKit](http://www.juicekit.org/) (built on Adobe Flex), but I would prefer something that would reside within C# .Net since that is what the web app is built on.

If no one knows of anything else then has anyone had experience with either [ThinkMap SDK](http://www.thinkmap.com/thinkmapsdk.jsp) or [JuiceKit](http://www.juicekit.org/)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [NodeXL](http://www.codeplex.com/NodeXL). It's free (on CodePlex) - with source. It came out of Microsoft, originally, I think.

It's WPF, but given you get the source, I'm sure it could be ported to other .NET technologies.